# Dynamics CRM Export Solution (not on-premises)

Tags: powershell, deployment, dynamics-crm

I want to export a Dynamics CRM 365 solution. Tools like the ALM Toolkit e.g. didn't worked.

My Questions:

1) Is it possible to export the entire CRM365 solution by powershell at all?

2) If it is not possible by powershell - is it possible by c#?

I can connect to the crm withouth problems by powershell. But If I try to call

When I call this:

```
$domain = "https://mypath.com"
$username = "user"
$password = "password"
$secPassword = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secPassword.AppendChar($_)}
$credentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secPassword

$conn = Get-CrmConnection -Url "https://mypath.com" -Credential $credentials 
$exportPath = "C:\Users\xy\Data" 
Import-Module "C:\Users\xy\Scripts\Adxstudio.Xrm.PowerShell\Adxstudio.Xrm.PowerShell.dll" 
Export-CrmContent -Connection $conn -OutputPath $exportPath -Uncompressed -Generalized
```

I get the following error:

```
Export-CrmContent : Metadata Contains A Reference That Cannot Be Resolved: "https://mypath/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc?wsdl=wsdl0".
In C:\Users\my.ps1:14 Char:1
+ Export-CrmContent -Connection $conn -OutputPath $exportPath -Uncompre ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo : NotSpecified: (:) [Export-CrmContent], InvalidOperationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Adxstudio.Xrm.PowerShell.Cmdlets.ExportCrmContent
```

But if I set up the $conn by using this:

```
$conn= Get-CrmConnection -OrganizationName MyOrg -DeploymentRegion MyRegion -OnLineType Office365 -Credential $credentials
```

I can get the organizations without problems. But when I try to call the export method with this connection I get:

```
The Parameter "$conn" cannot be bound. The value "Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" of the type "Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient" can't be converted to "Adxstudio.Xrm.PowerShell.Cmdlets.PsCrmConnection".
```

Are there any ideas to solve one of the both problems to export the crm solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not tried the Powershell approach, [but I've achieved this using C# in the past](https://woodsworkblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/21/crm-2011-export-unmanaged-solutions-programatically/).

```
static void ExportUnManagedSolutions(IOrganizationService service, String directory)
{
    //Find all the solutions
    QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
    {
        EntityName = "solution",
        ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("friendlyname", "uniquename", "version"),
        Criteria = new FilterExpression()
        {
            Conditions =
            {
                //Unmanaged solutions only
                new ConditionExpression("ismanaged", ConditionOperator.Equal, false),

                //These are special CRM solutions, which are marked as unmanaged but cant actually be exported
                new ConditionExpression("friendlyname", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "Active Solution"),
                new ConditionExpression("friendlyname", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "Default Solution"),
                new ConditionExpression("friendlyname", ConditionOperator.NotEqual, "Basic Solution"),
            }
        }
    };

    EntityCollection solutions = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

    //For each solution found
    foreach (Entity s in solutions.Entities)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Exporting " + s["friendlyname"]);

        //Perform a solution export
        ExportSolutionRequest request = new ExportSolutionRequest();
        request.Managed = false;
        request.SolutionName = (String)s["uniquename"];

        ExportSolutionResponse response = (ExportSolutionResponse)service.Execute(request);

        byte[] exportXml = response.ExportSolutionFile;
        string filename = (String)s["uniquename"] + " " + (String)s["version"] + ".zip";

        //This assumes the file directory already exists
        File.WriteAllBytes(directory + filename, exportXml);

        Console.WriteLine("Solution exported to {0}.", directory + filename);
    }
}
```